# Beautifulsoup removing HTML tags when parsing XML

Tags: python, html, xml, beautifulsoup

I have some HTML nested in a XML document between some other deeper nested tags that still contains HTML, BODY, and HEAD tags but Beautifulsoup is removing/changing them. Is there a way to prevent BS from destroying the order of these tags?

edit code added:

```
html1 = """
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<sss>
  <aaa>
    <bbbb>
      <ppe>
        <html class="a-no-js" data-19ax5a9jf="dingo">
         <head>
          <script type="text/javascript">
          </script>
          <script type="text/javascript">
          </script>
          <script type="text/javascript">
          </script>
          <script language="Javascript1.1" type="text/javascript">
          </script>
          <title>
          </title>
          <script type="text/javascript">
          </script>
         </head>
         <body class="pet_products en_US" id="dp">
          <div id="a-page">
           <script>
           </script>
           <script type="text/javascript">
           </script>
           <div id="PrimeStripeContent">
           </div>
           <div id="rwImages_hidden" style="display:none;">
           </div>
           <div class="a-container">
           </div>
          </div>
         </body>
        </html>
      </ppe>
    </bbbb>
  </aaa>
</sss>"""

html = BeautifulSoup(html1)

print html.prettify()
```

it rips the html, head, and body tags right out and rearranges it

Comment: Can you share the BS code you are using and an example data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When parsing XML files using BeautifulSoup, the constructor should be

```
html = BeautifulSoup(html1, features="xml")
```

as documented [here](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#id17). In order to use the xml features however, `lxml` needs to be installed. Installation instructions [here](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#installing-a-parser).

```
>>> html = BeautifulSoup(html1, features="xml")
>>> print html.prettify()
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<sss>
 <aaa>
  <bbbb>
   <ppe>
    <html class="a-no-js" data-19ax5a9jf="dingo">
     <head>
      <script type="text/javascript">
      </script>
      <script type="text/javascript">
      </script>
      <script type="text/javascript">
      </script>
      <script language="Javascript1.1" type="text/javascript">
      </script>
      <title>
      </title>
      <script type="text/javascript">
      </script>
     </head>
     <body class="pet_products en_US" id="dp">
      <div id="a-page">
       <script>
       </script>
       <script type="text/javascript">
       </script>
       <div id="PrimeStripeContent">
       </div>
       <div id="rwImages_hidden" style="display:none;">
       </div>
       <div class="a-container">
       </div>
      </div>
     </body>
    </html>
   </ppe>
  </bbbb>
 </aaa>
</sss>
```

Comment: Thank you, that helps fix a lot I didn't realize you needed the extra flag for XML.